# In Swift how can I make different implementations of a class depending on whether it is declared var or let?

Tags: swift

In swift both the Array and Dictionary classes have different implementations depending on whether you declare them variable or constant.  My question is can this type of functionality be used on classes you define, or is this reserved for Array, Dictionary?

Comment: how do you know they have different implementations? also, `mutating` is the keyword to make a method callable on `var` struct but not `let`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of Array and Dictionary are not different for variables and constants -- instead, `mutating` methods (methods that change the value of any part of a struct) are only callable for variables (declared with `var`) but not callable for constants (declared with `let`).

That is to say:

```
struct MyType {
    var name: String

    func capitalizedName() -> String {
        return name.capitalized()
    }

    mutating func setName(newName: String) {
        self.name = newName
    }
}

var myVariable = MyType(name: "Foo")
myVariable.setName("Bar")
println(myVariable.capitalizedName())  // print BAR

let myConstant = MyType(name: "Baz")
// not allowed by compiler:
// myConstant.setName("Nope!")
```

Comment: Thanks I looked up mutating that is what I was looking for :)